# Sendmail multiple SMTP account

Tags: smtp, sendmail

I would like to set two SMTP accounts with sendmail. I have successfully set up for one account, but I am not sure how to set up the second account with sendmail and use it.

sendmail.mc

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`[smtp.office365.com]')dnl
define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587')dnl
define(`ESMTP_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587')dnl
define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A p')dnl
TRUST_AUTH_MECH(`EXTERNAL DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
FEATURE(`authinfo',`hash -o /etc/mail/authinfo/office365-auth.db')dnl
```

I would appreciate if anyone could help me with this matter.

Answer (score 0):

**By default** sendmail (by sendmail.org) delivers email to "per OS account mailboxes".
=> create OS (operating system) account.

sendmail can support more complicated configurations but you have not indicated it.